# Why have I already the Columnheader in the Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid with some "old" columns from the last monitoring, now when i start a new monitoring, I watch how many columns i need next time and create or delete the columns.

Here is the syntax

```
if (anzAlteVar < anzNeueVar)
{
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
    int zahler = 1;
    string szahler;

    for (int j = 0; j <= dgTable3.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        szahler = zahler.ToString();
        dgTable3.Columns[j].Header = szahler;
        zahler++;
    }

    while (dgTable3.Columns.Count() != anzNeueVar)
    {
        szahler = zahler.ToString();
        textColumn.Header = szahler;
        dgTable3.Columns.Add(textColumn);
        zahler++;
    }
}

//übernimmt die neuen Header in das Datagrid
for (int i = 0; i <= dgTable3.Columns.Count-1; i++)
{
    dgTable3.Columns[i].Header = inhaltVar[i, 0];
}
```

My problem at the line `dgTable3.Columns.Add(textColumn);`at the second while loop pass I get the error

> System.ArgumentException

because I have two columns with the same name.

My question: How is that possible that I have the same name twice? I mean I change the header every time it goes through the loop and add them after the new name is given. I watched it at the Debugger and on them i have every header only one time, please help me and write what i made wrong and what i must change.

Friendly wishes sniffi

Comment: I think you should create new column in loop  not out side. `DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();`. In you case, it refers to same column and that is why it returns error.

Comment: Did it work or not? Please share proper details so other people can take benefit from it.

Comment: 1000 Thanks it work perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new column in loop not out side. `DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();`.

In your case, it refers to same column and that is why it returns error.

```
while (dgTable3.Columns.Count() != anzNeueVar)
{
    szahler = zahler.ToString();

    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
    textColumn.Header = szahler;

    dgTable3.Columns.Add(textColumn);
    zahler++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You define the `textColumn` outside of the loop. So you access one and the same column in each iteration of the loops.
When you try to add the column with `dgTable3.Columns.Add(textColumn);` a second time, the column has already been added and you're trying to add the same column twice, hence the error that two columns have the same name. (The error should rather say that the column is already part of the collection)

```
while (dgTable3.Columns.Count() != anzNeueVar)
{
    szahler = zahler.ToString();

    // Move the declaration here
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn {Header = szahler};

    dgTable3.Columns.Add(textColumn);
    zahler++;
}
```